# Not able to set tintcolor to image set as background in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tintcolor

I am facing trouble setting a tint color to my images which are set as background for my uitableviewcells.

The following is my code:

```
backgroundImage.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
cell.backgroundView = backgroundImage
cell.backgroundView!.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

The images are showing normally without any tint added to them.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: My `backgroundImage` is a UIImageView. I am setting an image to it and then doing the above. I tried changing `backgroundImage.tintColor` too but no change happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the first line with this: `backgroundImage.image = backgroundImage!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)`